# python psycopg2 table name from a variable

Tags: python, for-loop, psycopg2

I want to choose the name of the table using a variable from a loop.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgres' user='postgres' 
password='password'")
c = conn.cursor()

query = 'select * From "employees"'
c.execute(query)

for row in c:
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "row[2]" ("department" text)')
```

The result of this execute is a table named `row`, but I want the value of the variable. So what I want is `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Variable-from-loop`.

Any suggestion?

---

To make it more simple:

I have file1 with the below contents:

```
-table1
-table2
-table3
-table4
```

I will use a for loop and I want to make all these tables at once:

```
for i in file1:
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS i ("department" text)')
```

Comment: The loop works just fine and i can print the value of row[2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to replace the variable in the string before executing the statement?

Like this:

```
table_name_list = [
    'alfa',
    'beta',
]

for name in table_name_list:
    sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} ("department" text)'.format(name)
    print(sql)
    c.execute(sql)
```